# From cURL to JavaScript fetch()

Tags: javascript, rest, curl

I have a cURL example of an request to a rest API, but I can't seem to replicate it correctly in JavaScript with fetch. Would any of you please help me out? here is the cURL example:

`curl https://api.sparebank1.no/open/personal/banking/accounts/all --header "Authorization:Bearer 9VKwFeoS8QfeQEeFxD5MiOf6YlFQR0nOpLF1ZUrHRrWqp3rY7G13hy"`

Thx

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```js
fetch('https://api.sparebank1.no/open/personal/banking/accounts/all', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer 9VKwFeoS8QfeQEeFxD5MiOf6YlFQR0nOpLF1ZUrHRrWqp3rY7G13hy'
  }
});
```

The fetch function takes a first parameter, the URL. The second parameter is an object containing keys that describe your request, such as `method` or `headers`.

In our case, it's specifying a headers object. This contains key-value pairs of named headers and their corresponding values.

I recommend viewing [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (if you haven't), it's a useful resource.